# how to notify condition variable in another class, c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I have a groups of objects, each object has two threads: Task thread processes the data and notifies Decision thread that the data is ready, then waits for Decision thread to make the decision whether to continue operations; Decision thread waits Task thread for the data, then consumes the data and make a decision ( notify Task thread that the decision is ready to fetch ).

```
Task.cpp:

class Task{
    public:
        void DoTask(){
             // process data
             {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
                data_ready = true;
                cv_data.notify_one();

                while( decision_ready == false )
                    cv_decision.wait( lck );
              }
              if ( decision )
                  // continue task
              else
                  // quit
        }

        void SetDecision( bool flag )  {  decision = flag;  }
        bool GetDataFlag() const {  return data_ready;  } 
        bool SetDecisionFlag( bool flag ) { decision_ready = flag; } 

        std::mutex mtx; 
        std::condition_variable cv_data;
        std::condition_variable cv_decision;

    private:
         bool decision;
         bool data_ready;
         bool decision_ready;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
void Decision ( Task *task );

int main(){
    Task mytask[10];
    std::thread do[10];
    std::thread decision[10];
    for(int i=0; i< 10; ++i)
    {
         do[i] = std::thread( &Task::doTask, &mytask[i] );
         decision[i] = std::thread( Decision, &mytask[i] );
         do[i].detach();
         decision[i].detach();
    }
}

void Decision( Task *task )
{
    st::mutex mtx_decision;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck( task->mtx );
    while( task->GetDataFlag() == false )
         task->cv_data.wait(lck);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx_decision);
    // check database and make decision

    task->SetDecision( true );
    task->SetDecisionFlag( true );
    task->cv_decision.notify_one();
}
```

What is the problem with this approach? The program works well only in single thread case. If I actually open two or more threads, I get segmentation fault. I am not sure how to pass the condition variables between different scopes. And hope someone can tell me the right way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Your `main` function runs off the end, terminating the process.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need the same mutex and same conditional variable to get it working. Now each class gets own mutex and condition_variable and each decision too.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Because each task works independently, each task needs its own mutex and condition_variable to synchronize the task operation and decision making.

Comment: I can't see anything here. Did you check coredump? Or did you execute binary in gdb? Stacktrace is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason while your application crashes is because you detach your threads and than your main() exits, killing threads in the midst of what they are doing. I strongly advice against using detached threads.